# Hyperlink for square brackets inside inline code

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, inline-code

Adding a hyperlink for inline code with square brackets via the tool button (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) gives the wrong enclosing:

E.g.:

> text `[]` text

produces:

> text [`\[\]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298206) text

instead of

> text [`[]`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298206) text